# Custom post type submenu capabilities - custom plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I'm trying to add new custom capability so I can hide custom post type from non admins. In my custom post type I have some custom taxonomies and then 2 submenus. The administrator can see the menu of the custom post type, the taxonomies and the submenus, but other users can only see the submenus. But when I try to apply the add_role on the activation hook the submenus are not shown. I also tried with add_cap and the same happens. I also tried to add capabilities in the custom post type and then just the taxonomies were shown. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

EDIT:
As requested in the comment, this is how I add the 2 submenus:

```
     add_action('admin_menu','bsp_plugin_menu');
     function bsp_plugin_menu(){
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=badge', 'Add new student', 'Add new students', 'manage-options','add-new-students','bsp_add_new_students');
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=badge', 'Show students', 'Show students', 'manage_options','show-students','bsp_students_show');   
}
```

Comment: Please share how you are adding the submenus (code excerpt).

Comment: I edited the question with requested code. @ambroseya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my question...
I don't know if it is the best approach: In the custom post type I added capabilities to which only admin has priviliges like so:

```
    'capabilities'=>array(
        'edit_post'=>'update_core',
        'read_post'=>'update_core',
        'delete_post'=>'update_core',
        'edit_posts'=>'update_core',
        'edit_others_posts'=>'update_core',
        'publish_posts'=>'update_core',
        'read_private_posts'=>'update_core'
    ),
```

And then I also did that for custom taxonomies like so:

```
    'capabilities'=>array(
    'manage_terms'=>'manage_options',
    'edit_terms'=>'manage_options',
    'delete_terms'=>'manage_options',
    'assign_terms'=>'manage_options',
    ),
```

So only admin can see it and manage it. 
For the submenu in the capability parameter I just entered the capability which administrator, editor and author have in common (publish_posts).

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=badge', 'Add new student', 'Add new students', 'publish_posts','add-new-students','bsp_add_new_students');
```